# Deploy throw warning on jboss wildfly application

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly, warnings

when i deploy a project to wildfly serve i got this warning

```
21:09:51,648 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class org.wildfly.security.mp.jwt.JWTCDIExtension in Module "deployment.eSchoolDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/wildfly/security/mp/jwt/JWTCDIExtension (Module "deployment.eSchoolDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader): io/smallrye/jwt/auth/cdi/SmallRyeJWTAuthCDIExtension
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:839)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadExtension(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:129)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadAttachments(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:115)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.deploy(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

21:09:51,740 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0007: Could not load portable extension class org.wildfly.security.mp.jwt.JWTCDIExtension: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/wildfly/security/mp/jwt/JWTCDIExtension (Module "deployment.eSchoolDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader): io/smallrye/jwt/auth/cdi/SmallRyeJWTAuthCDIExtension
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:839)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadExtension(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:129)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadAttachments(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:115)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.deploy(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

how can solve this warning, wwhat is the jars that i need for this warning??
also how can i solve this warning

```
[org.jboss.as.weld] (default task-1) WFLYWELD0052: Using deployment classloader to load proxy classes for module org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs. Package-private access will not work. To fix this the module should declare dependencies on [org.jboss.weld.core, org.jboss.weld.spi, org.jboss.weld.api]
21:12:13,373 WARN  [org.jboss.as.weld] (default task-1) WFLYWELD0052: Using deployment classloader to load proxy classes for module org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider. Package-private access will not work. To fix this the module should declare dependencies on [org.jboss.weld.core, org.jboss.weld.spi, org.jboss.weld.api]
21:12:20,078 WARN  [org.jboss.as.weld] (default task-1) WFLYWELD0052: Using deployment classloader to load proxy classes for module org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider. Package-private access will not work. To fix this the module should declare dependencies on [org.jboss.weld.core, org.jboss.weld.spi, org.jboss.weld.api]
```

note i add to pom.xml the org.jboss.weld.core,org.jboss.weld.spi and org.jboss.weld.api and still not work

thank you.

Comment: Can you post your pom?

Comment: sure i can post it

Comment: Do you really need all those dependencies? I would guess a lot of them are not needed. Nearly all of them should be marked with `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: okay, i 'am new in this domain, i do not know a lot.
thank you very much for your response .

Comment: The majority of those dependencies can likely be removed. Most of the other ones should be marked as `<scope>provided</scope>` as the container provides them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>eSchoolDemo</groupId>
  <artifactId>eSchoolDemo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  
  
  <dependencies>
      

    <!-- Hibernat Congifuration -->
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.18.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.30.Final</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.30.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>  
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
  
    <!-- End of Hibernate -->

  
  
  <!-- Dependencies needed after creation -->
  <!--   -->
  
  
  
  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.activation</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0.SP01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.inject-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-MR1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.management.j2ee</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.resource</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.auth.message</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaspi-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.jacc</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jacc-api_1.5_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jsp-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>taglibs-standard-compat</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.6-RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.6-RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.6-RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.soap</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-saaj-api_1.4_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxws-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>picketbox</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>picketbox-commons</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>picketbox-infinispan</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-controller-client</artifactId>
      <version>11.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-dmr</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
      <version>3.11.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.11.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>3.11.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
      <version>3.11.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.batch</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-batch-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.enterprise.concurrent</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-concurrency-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.websocket</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-common</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-asn1</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-audit</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-auth</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-auth-server</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-auth-server-deprecated</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-auth-server-http</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-auth-server-sasl</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-auth-util</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-base</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-credential</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-credential-source-deprecated</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-credential-source-impl</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-credential-store</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-digest</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-http</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-http-basic</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-http-bearer</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-http-cert</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-http-deprecated</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-http-digest</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-http-form</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-http-spnego</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-http-sso</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-http-util</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-jacc</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-jaspi</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-json-util</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-keystore</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-mechanism</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-mechanism-digest</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-mechanism-gssapi</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-mechanism-http</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-mechanism-oauth2</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-mechanism-scram</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-password-impl</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-permission</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-provider-util</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-realm</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-realm-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-realm-ldap</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-realm-token</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-sasl</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-sasl-anonymous</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-sasl-auth-util</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-sasl-deprecated</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-sasl-digest</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-sasl-entity</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-sasl-external</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-sasl-gs2</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-sasl-gssapi</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-sasl-localuser</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-sasl-oauth2</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-sasl-otp</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-sasl-plain</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-sasl-scram</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-security-manager</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-security-manager-action</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-ssl</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-util</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-x500</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-x500-cert</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-x500-cert-acme</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-x500-cert-util</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-x500-deprecated</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-x500-principal</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

 
  </dependencies>
  
  
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>12</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```